# Can't install Georgian QWERTY keyboard on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-14.04

can you help me to install Georgian language qwerty keyboard layout. I have xubuntu 14

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look: [Permanently change keyboard layout on Ubuntu](http://krisreeves.com/things-that-should-be-easy/permanently-change-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-server-11-10/)

You need to edit `/etc/default/keyboard`. After that, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` console-setup to commit your settings.

When you run console-setup, it compiles in the keyboard layout listed in that file, which is why console-data’s changes were not kept. In the file are four lines:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
 XKBLAYOUT="ge"
 XKBVARIANT=""
 XKBOPTIONS=""
```

(ge Georgian)